# How do I handle this error : No overload for 'SQLDisplay_Date_records' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

So I basically have two textboxes in the aspx file which get populated by dates (using the jquery datepicker) as given below

```
Start Date: <asp:TextBox ID="TxtDatepicker_start" runat="server" Width = 125px >
  </asp:TextBox>

  &nbsp;&nbsp;End Date: <asp:TextBox ID="TxtDatepicker_end" runat="server" Width = 125px >
  </asp:TextBox>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button_daterecords" runat="server"  Text="Show records"  OnClick ="SQLDisplay_Date_records" /><br />
```

However when I try to determine what  has been stored in the text boxes for further processing in the code behind using this function

```
protected void SQLDisplay_Date_records()
        {
            string date1 = TxtDatepicker_end.Text;
            string date2 = TxtDatepicker_end.Text;
        }
```

I am getting this error

```
No overload for 'SQLDisplay_Date_records' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'
```

Can someone explain this to me ,I apologize for the naive question but I am still making my way around with ASP.NET and C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess,  OnClick is a event. which has a object (source) and eventargs.

Try setting it to

```
Protected void SQLDisplay_Date_records(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string date 1 = TxtDatepicker_end.Text;
    string date 2 = TxtDatepicker_end.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method signature is incorrect.

The `protected void SQLDisplay_Date_records()`

should be `protected void SQLDisplay_Date_records(object sender, EventArgs e)`

As it is an `OnClick` Event and it should take an Event Argument as a parameter.